# OGC API Features and GeoServer

Tags: service, geoserver, ogc

im trying to create an OGC API Features server.

I know there is a community module named ogcapi for GeoServer and i was able to install the module (by copying all classes of the ogcapi module into the geoserver/web-inf/lib folder of my apache tomcat)

I can see the new Service Capabilities in the Web administration interface but i have no idea how to move on. There is no further possibility in the Services Panel.

Is there any documentation on how to use the ogcapi-plugin? Does anybody already use it and can give some hints on how to move on?

Im thankful for every help approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a community module, you should be using a nightly build of the development version of GeoServer, along with the corresponding OGC API module.
If you have them installed, you'll get something like this in the home page:

[image]

The FEATURES 1.0 link will bring you to the landing page of the OGC Feature API implementation. From there, you can use information from the Features API specification itself to use the API.

Comment: Hey Andrea, thank you very much for your fast answer. That was exactly the hint i was looking for!